# Problems with MATLAB Engine API for Java

Tags: java, eclipse, matlab, api, jar

Im am trying to compile this piece of code:

```
import com.mathworks.engine.*;

public class javaEvalFunc {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MatlabEngine eng = MatlabEngine.startMatlab();
        eng.evalAsync("[X, Y] = meshgrid(-2:0.2:2);");
        eng.evalAsync("Z = X .* exp(-X.^2 - Y.^2);");
        Object[] Z = eng.getVariable("Z");
        eng.close();
        }
}
```

I found it on this web page: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/evaluate-matlab-expression-from-java.html

As you can see I need a reference to com.mathworks.engine.*;

This Page [Mathworks Engine Info](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/setup-environment.html#bvcubp5) says that the .jar file that I need to Add is in this Path:

matlabroot/extern/engines/java/jar/engine.jar

But in my computer I just have a folder called phyton in this path

matlabroot/extern/engines

[image]

Where can Ifind the .jar file that I need ?

I am using Eclipse IDE by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. You are looking in the right spot but your version of matlab doesn't support the Java Engine. You need to have Matlab R2016**b** or higher. It's not very clear in the documentation. 

So i suggest that you download the newest version if your license permits that. Otherwise you can use a different interface to connect to matlab. [matlabcontrol](https://github.com/jakaplan/matlabcontrol/wiki/Walkthrough) is often used for the same purpose but its quite old and poor documented.